# How to add array in existing oracle sql cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am dealing with more than 25 tables which having association and I need to return a simple array/cursor from my stored procedure.
To make simple my question I am providing below example:-

For mentioned below scenario I want to add subjects against each student means in existing emp_curr I want to add result of sub_cur.

```
cursor emp_curr is
     select st_id,st_name,st_surname from student;
BEGIN
     FOR n IN emp_curr LOOP
     DECLARE
          cursor sub_cur is
          select sub_id,subject from student_subjects where st_id_fk=n.st_id;
     BEGIN
           FOR c IN sub_cur LOOP
           -- Here I want to store sub_cur values in existing emp_curr 
          end loop;
       END;
     end loop;
END;
```

Final Output

`|-----------|--------------|----------|---------------|-
|Student ID | Student Name |Student ID|Student subject|
|-----------|--------------|----------|---------------|-
|   1       |  prashant    |    2     |    Maths      |
|   1       |  prashant    |    4     |    English    |
|   1       |  prashant    |    3     |    Science    |
|-----------|--------------|----------|---------------|-
|   2       |  shailndra   |    1     |    Hindi      |
|   2       |  shailndra   |    5     |    Geo        |
|   2       |  shailndra   |    7     |    Chemical   |
|-----------|--------------|----------|---------------|-`

It will be great if you can help me as I have already spent 4 hours and its gone in vain.

Comment: You can't change the name or number of fields returned by a cursor once it has been opened. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis so what is the best way to do that I just need output with each employee having how many subjects.It means we cant do in oracle procedure, I dont want to do in simple join as I have complex query in real.

Answer (score 0):

Prashant Thakre, how are you? Perhaps I misunderstood your question, so I will explain myself and hopefully, help you. The first thing I realized from your scenario is it's odd. You cannot change an Oracle cursor structure once you have declared it. More than that, I don't see the need to implement such a procedure. You use two columns from the table STUDENT, am I right? Then, you need two more columns added to your data set, those two coming from the table STUDENT_SUBJECTS. And it seems to exist some referential integrity between those tables, because you have an equijoin condition in the second cursor's query ( ...where st_id_fk=n.st_id)

So, I wonder, why don't you open the first cursor setting the following query, so you don't need to add those columns "by hand"?

select s.st_id,s.st_name,s.st_surname,sb.sub_id,sb.subject
from student s,student_subjects sb
where s.st_id=sb.st_id_fk

Using that query, you have want you are looking for, what you are needing. 
Again, maybe I misunderstood your issue, but I really want to help you. So, give more ight"on the subject if that query is not what you need.

Best regards.
Jorge.

Comment: Thanks for your help but actually I have to deal with 25 tables and which having a lot associations that can be done only help of procedure. I asked question in simple way so it be ease to understand and can help the answer to accomplish by difficult task to deal with 25 tables as I need to also use IF ELSE condition in many placess so I cant go for simple join or something like that. Thanks again for your quick reply.